# How to disable the keys of the phone programmatically during runtime

Tags: android, keyboard

Inside my Jumbled words game app, I want a way such that only the alphabet keys of the keyboard are enabled, depending on the scrambled words appearing. For example, `"rrowa"` is a scrambled form of the word "arrow" and only the keys `'a', 'r', 'o', 'w`' must be enabled and the remaining keys must be disabled. When a next scrambled word appears for examples `"nife"` which is a scrambled form of "fine", only alphabets `'f', 'i', 'n', 'e'` must be enabled. How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == "your key") {
            return true;

        }else return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

You need to find out the key code using [Key Event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)